# Add `\n` to JTextArea every wrap the word

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

Hello I have a JTextArea and I `txtResult.setWrapStyleWord program (true);`, and I also have a report which takes data from JTextArea.

I want every automatic JTextArea wrap, then add a new row, `\ n` , so in my report have same text align.

Please help, thank you :)

Comment: there is wordwrap and linewrap, `Please help, thank you :) ` == for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), just about JFrame and JTextArea, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 2):

You should not insert the "\n" into the text area. Instead you should create a helper method to do this when you want to save the text. The code would be something like:

```
public String formatText(JTextArea textArea)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder( textArea.getText() );
    int lineHeight = textArea.getFontMetrics( textArea.getFont() ).getHeight();
    Point view = new Point(textArea.getWidth(), textArea.getInsets().top);
    int length = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
    int endOfLine = textArea.viewToModel(view);
    int lines = 0;

    while (endOfLine < length)
    {
        int adjustedEndOfLine = endOfLine + lines;

        if (text.charAt(adjustedEndOfLine) == ' ')
        {
            text.insert(adjustedEndOfLine + 1, '\n');
            lines++;
        }

        view.y += lineHeight;
        endOfLine = textArea.viewToModel(view);
    }

    return text.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 I don't have a Java env to test this algorithm but I am guessing (from what I can understand of the code) that it works (I don't see why it wouldn't).

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, thanks for the vote of confidence. I did limited testing on a text area that uses word wrapping.